# Creating node with multiple subscribers working on shared data

Tags: ros2, nodes, multithreading, subscribers

I'm working with ROS2.

Suppose I have a state estimator taking in multiple data forms at different rates, ex IMU and GPS or something similar.

My state estimator will be a single node and this node will need callbacks for both IMU and GPS.

At each update a routine will be called to update the state which will be shared within the node between subscribers.

How do I run multiple subscribers in the same node?

Comment: Apologies if this is too simple, but have you simply tried to create 2 subscribers/callbacks and spin? In ROS1 I had a statemachine node that had many subscribers running with callbacks updating state variables.

Comment: I have not and honestly ROS2 is pretty terrible at documentation/examples. Also what ways would be OK to share information between nodes?

Comment: I should be more clear, between multiple subscribers/publishers in the same process.

Comment: In your understanding is a node not a process? I'm trying to understand the question.

Comment: I think I figured it out, the confusion was basically how a publisher/subscriber gets created. The tutorial didn't do a good job clarifying that you can create multiple ones in the same node. For some reason I thought the node was defined in terms of being only one of them.